# Using aria-label to locate and insert value with Python3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to locate and insert value inside a 'value' field.

As you can see the following HTML code the value is empty, I'm trying to locate the element to insert a new value to it but unable to find.

```
<input aria-label="" id="tab-shared-widget-2" class="" data-tb-test-id="auth-component-password-text-field-TextInput" type="password" value=""
```

I've tried to locate the element using XPath and by CSS Selector and for some reason my web driver still doesn't find the element using both ways.

```
susername = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#tab-shared-widget-2")
    susername.send_keys("Something")
spassword = driver.find_element_by_xpath("tab-shared-widget-2").get_attribute('value')
    spassword.send_keys("Something")
```

Comment: The `xpath` you used won't work, but the `css_selector` should. I'm guessing the field is inside `<iframe>`, if it is you need to switch to it first. You can also try adding some [wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

Comment: Thought about that approach and I've added a time.sleep of a few seconds

Comment: Adding sleep won't resolve the `<iframe>` issue...

Comment: So thanks for the advice will try that approach and update.

Comment: Added ```driver.implicitly_wait(10)``` to the code and still the same.

Comment: Adding any kind of wait won't handle `iframe` if it exist.